# Whats the best approach for my project?

Tags: android, performance, gps, locationmanager

Am developing a tracking app for android where user will be tracked for 8hrs minimum a day.
data will be retrieved from GPS and once data retrieved it will be sent to server.

What I have done till now is

data will be retrieved every 30 seconds if he is on bike (speed >= 13mph) if less than that then every 1sec.

created a activity and using requestlocationupdates() retrieving data and sending to server using asynchronous tasks.

I saw many ppl recommending service for long run tasks and alarm manager instead of using minTime and minMeters of requestlocationupdates().

So am confused.

What would be best approach for this? am mainly developing it for low end devices so battery is my main constraint.

And tracking should not get stopped.

Comment: You absolutely can't guarantee that tracking won't be stopped. There are so many things that you don't control and which could cause your tracking to fail.

Comment: Yes I know android system kills app if it needs memory etc. but wanted to know the good approach to go at least to some extent my app will be safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If battery is your concern, you don't want to use GPS.  GPS kills the battery.  You want to use network location instead.  Its less accurate, but much nicer on the battery.

I did something similar for driving, I used a service and an alarm rather than the minimum time and distance, just because using fixed time intervals made my math easier.

Comment: Network location does not solve the problem.  Consider, among other things his requirement to check (speed <= 13mph) Try that with network location.   You are correct, though, that you aren't going to be able to run the GPS for eight hours on battery.

Comment: I've written this app for driving.  Network location worked fine

Comment: @GabeSechan network location worked fine?? 1000m accuracy you call fine?

Comment: If all you want to see is if you're going above a certain speed, yes.  I have an app on the play store that does it now-  detects when going over 10 mph, and if so allows you to listen to and respond to texts by voice.  I had to add a few heuristics to it, but it did not need GPS.

Comment: I have did checking speed using getspeed() of location class its enough right? which method you have used?

Comment: Not all implementations include speed in the location class.  The GPS in my phone doesn't.  If it exists, its probably the best way.  My mechanism was simple-  poll at regular intervals and divide the difference in location by the difference in time.

Comment: My phone has that but great that you made me aware of this, I will try to consider this situation and use your method.

Answer (score 0):

If using [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) is an option, APIs like the [DetectedActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html) might be useful for you.  From what I've read, they spent some time working on making the API smart about things like battery life and location services.

Comment: So you guys think running gps for 8hrs is not good idea with 30 seconds or more interval? my accuracy constraint is 50-100meters so I cant use network based location I guess.

Comment: ya sure I will check that